# Is this iOS bug or can it be fixed by developer?

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, report, bug-tracking

I am using crash reporting tool [Crashlytics](http://beta.crashlytics.com) for a while now and am very pleased with it. However I can not figure it out what some of the reported bugs means.

For example I get `CoreFoundation` error `_CFAutoreleasePoolPop`:
[image: Crashlytics bug report 1]

Or another one in `UIKit` -> `__73-[UIPopoverController _completionBlockForDismissalWhenNotifyingDelegate:]`:
[image: Crashlytics bug report 2]

Are this kind of bugs iOS bugs or bugs that my code produced? What can I do here?

Comment: My guess is you're overreleasing something. Unless you're using ARC, in which case you're more likely under-retaining something. Perhaps a delegate object which only has the weak reference to it from its delegating object?

Comment: I am using ARC. What does this mean "under-retaining something"?

Comment: Like you allocated an object and have weak references to it but no strong ones, so it gets deallocated yet you can still send it messages (and causing crashes). Common culprits here are delegate properties with an assign type rather than strong.

Comment: I am using delegates with unsafe_unretained type for iOS <= 4.3 and weak for newer versions of iOS: https://gist.github.com/1563325

Comment: these are all generated due to lack of memory handling(release/ retain) done on your end and are not iOS bugs.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to find this little bugs...

Comment: What else can I do if I'm using ARC ?

Answer (score 0):

`UIAlertView` seems to be implemented with `UIPopovers` and are therefore `UIAlertViews` which can cause this issue. I suspect that the `UIPopoverController` or `UIAlertView` delegate has been deallocated before the completion handler is called causing the crash.

If you keep a __weak reference to the `UIAlertViews` and `UIPopoverControllers` in their delegates you can set the alert/popover's delegate property to nil in delegate's dealloc call without unnecessarily retaining `popover/alert`.